# New app won't scaffold with Jade templates

Tags: towerjs

When scaffolding a new tower js app i execute

```
tower new demo --views jade
```

but i still get the default CoffeeKup layouts.

Any help with this would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature hasn't been implemented yet, only the command line flags have been setup so far. Here are the generator templates:

- [lib/tower/server/generator/generators/tower](https://github.com/viatropos/tower/tree/026416121143dd9a7caf35e9dd1ec5e3ca195dae/lib/tower/server/generator/generators/tower)
- [lib/tower/server/generator/generators/tower/view/templates](https://github.com/viatropos/tower/tree/026416121143dd9a7caf35e9dd1ec5e3ca195dae/lib/tower/server/generator/generators/tower/view/templates)

To add this feature all that needs to be done is to wire the command line flags to the `viewGenerator.coffee` and `appGenerator.coffee` files:

- view generator script: [src/tower/server/generator/generators/tower/view/viewGenerator.coffee#L19](https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/026416121143dd9a7caf35e9dd1ec5e3ca195dae/src/tower/server/generator/generators/tower/view/viewGenerator.coffee#L19)
- the generator object gets passed a `program` variable: [src/tower/server/generator.coffee#L20](https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/026416121143dd9a7caf35e9dd1ec5e3ca195dae/src/tower/server/generator.coffee#L20)
- and here's the application generator command parser to see the variables set on the `program`: [src/tower/server/command/new.coffee](https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/026416121143dd9a7caf35e9dd1ec5e3ca195dae/src/tower/server/command/new.coffee)

So all that needs to be done is modify that `viewGenerator.coffee` script to something like:

```
for view in views
  @template "#{view}.coffee", "app/views/#{@view.directory}/#{view}.#{@program.engine}"
```

I would help implement this but don't have the time at the moment, working on merging the dev branch to master. Hope that helps.